# How to add custom attribute to kendo combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am working on web application using kendo UI and I need to add a custom attribute to combobox.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [use JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set an attribute:

Example:

```
<input id="combobox" style="width: 100%"/>

$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    filter: "startswith",
    dataSource: data,
    dataBound: onDataBound
});

function onDataBound(e) {
    $("#combobox").closest(".k-combobox").attr("someAttr", "someValue");
};
```

This will result in:

[image: Attr]

Comment: is that a right way? OR do we have any other way like below. {
                field: "ColumnName",
                title: "Column Name",
                attributes: {
                    class: "col-md-9 col-lg-9"
                },
                headerAttributes: {
                    class: "col-md-9 col-lg-9"
                }

Comment: That'd be for a Kendo Grid I guess. As far as I know the Combobox doesn't have those, unless you're using Kendo MVC, then you can use `HtmlAttributes()`.